# Getting only the most recent bookmark?

Tags: links, bookmark, get-bookmarks

So, I was thinking I'd use WordPress' Bookmarks/Links content type to populate a slider...

...Except there are a [grand](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_bookmarks) [total](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks) of [four](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmark) [functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmark_field) interacting with this part of WordPress.

I don't think you can even access these with a WP_Query object, and it seems all date-related data attached to these is in relation to the last update of the link itself (I.e., when the linked-to page is updated).

**Is there any way to even retrieve only the most recently-added bookmark?**

(For more of a semi-related discussion question for the comments -- if this aspect of WP is so woefully underdeveloped 3 versions of the CMS in, why not just farm out this functionality to a plugin? Simply backwards compatibility?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to query the links directly, but there is definetly a `link_updated` field in the [wp_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_links) table, so you can use `wpdb` to interact with it and return the latest (modified) links.

There's also a solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3901/how-to-splice-in-wp-links-links-into-the-loop/3910#3910).

**EDIT** : Updating a link doesn't change `link_updated`, but here is a plugin that can solve that : [Link Updated Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/link-updated/)

> Auttomatically update the link_updated field when adding or editing a
>   link, so you can use Links as a linklist.

**EDIT 2** : If using the Links/Bookmarks functionality is too much of a hassle, as it seems it's really not as flexible as posts, you could also create a custom post type or a post format for Bookmarks and work with that.

Comment: Isn't the value of `link_updated` the timestamp of that link's content's last update? I.e., not when the link was added or updated in WP, but rather, when that link's content is updated?

Comment: You're right, I just tried on a testsite, when I update a link it doesn't change `link_update`. By looking for info on that, I found a plugin that may do that though (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks, but half the reason for using weblinks in the first place was to avoid half of the templating work that goes hand-in-hand with custom post types... I've fallen back to just using a post category and custom fields in the meanwhile, but I'm still curious whether there's any way my above question can still be answered.